# Skip printing of row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to display data in chart from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

I use this SQL query:

```
select event_date, sum(case when type = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) as Error,
sum(case when type = 'Warn' then 1 else 0 end) as Warn, sum(case when type = 'Info' then 1 else 0 end) as Info, 
sum(case when type = 'Critical' then 1 else 0 end) as Critical 
from event e where event_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 15
group by event_date 
order by event_date
```

I get this result:

```
01-JAN-16   0   0   0   0
01-JAN-16   0   0   0   0
02-JAN-16   20  0   10  0
03-JAN-16   0   0   0   0
```

How I can skip the days in which I have 0 events?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN type IN ('Info', 'Warn', 'Error', 'Critical') THEN 1 END) > 0` after `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select event_date, sum(case when type = 'Error' then 1 else 0 end) as Error,
sum(case when type = 'Warn' then 1 else 0 end) as Warn, sum(case when type = 'Info' then 1 else 0 end) as Info, 
sum(case when type = 'Critical' then 1 else 0 end) as Critical 
from event e where event_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 15
group by event_date
having count(case when type IN ('Info', 'Warn', 'Error', 'Critical') then 1 end) > 0
order by event_date
```